# Turning off multiple vm's in ansible

Tags: ansible, vmware

I'm not sure if many people use this but I'm trying to shut down multiple vm's in vsphere in a specific order and turn them back on in a specific order but I can't seem to do that

Something like this works

```
- hosts: vmwaremaster
  tasks:
    - name: shutdown myguest
      vmware_guest:
        hostname: ip_of_vcenter
        password: pwassword_of_vcenter
        username: username_of_vcenter
        name: webserver01
        state: shutdownguest
```

But if I try to add more guests with the name module it fails

```
- hosts: vmwaremaster
  tasks:
    - name: shutdown myguest
      vmware_guest:
        hostname: ip_of_vcenter
        password: pwassword_of_vcenter
        username: username_of_vcenter
        name: webserver01, memcacheserver01, mysqlserver01,
        state: shutdownguest
```

I'm trying to find a way to shutdown a guest if the previous guest has been shutdown but don't see much documentation in ansible. Has anyone worked with this module?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a [loop](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html).

Comment: yeah, looking at the loop options and thats exactly what im looking for. I have never had the loop option work in the correct order before. Is there a way to confirm that the loop will shutdown vm's in the listed order?...or have I just been doing something wrong?

Comment: Loops just loop over the items you provide, in the order you provide them. If you're seeing things executing in an unexpected order, I suspect you're not feeding the loop the data you think you are.  If you want to update your question with something that you've tried and a description of the failure, we can probably help out.

Comment: The loops help with shutting down the vm's but the playbooke ends in failure. I found the issue in the loops with a naming issue in my inventory so this helped.

Answer (score 0):

I had the wrong datastore set in playbook. Loops were exactly what i was looking for.